# Convergence of $\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac {\sqrt[m]{n!}}{\sqrt[k]{(2n)!}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Does the following series converges ? $$\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac {\sqrt[m]{n!}}{\sqrt[k]{(2n)!}} \ \text{for} \ \ k,m\in \mathbb N$$

I tried the ratio test:

$ \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {\sqrt[m]{(n+1)!}}{\sqrt[k]{(2n+2)!}}\cdot \frac  {\sqrt[k]{(2n)!}}{\sqrt[m]{n!}} = ... =\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {(n+1)^{\large\frac{k-m}{mk}}}{(2(2n+1))^{\large\frac1 k}}$

Now I should check for cases with $m,k$ where the numerator is larger than the denominator and vice versa and when they're equal but it doesn't seem right...

Note: I can't use integration or Stirling approximation, nor Taylor.

Comment: See [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Comment: @Lucian I'm not supposed to use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the ratio you have and rewrite it slightly, you get

$$n^{\frac{1}{m} - \frac{2}{k}}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{(k-m)/(mk)}}{2^{2/k}\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^{1/k}}.$$

The fraction converges to

$$\frac{1}{2^{2/k}} < 1,$$

so it depends on the behaviour of $n^{1/m - 2/k}$. If $\frac{1}{m} > \frac{2}{k}$, the quotient tends to $+\infty$, if $\frac{1}{m} < \frac{2}{k}$, it tends to $0$, and in the case of equality, it tends to $2^{-2/k} \in (0,1)$.

So by the ratio test, the series converges if and only if $k \leqslant 2m$.

Comment: You mean the whole expression converges to $\frac{1}{2^{2/k}}$ ?

Comment: The fraction in the first equation, that is, without the $n^{1/m-2/k}$ factor. That one then determines how the quotient $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ behaves.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Set $k = rm$, you get the expression as 
$$\left( \frac{(n!)^r}{(2n)!} \right)^\frac{1}{m}$$

Use ratio test after that, you should get
$$\left| \frac{(n+1)^r}{(2n+2)(2n+1)}\right| < 1$$